# How to correctly parse JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, api

I want to parse values from an Json API, but I cant get it to work

The API returns this JSON:

```
[
  {
    "assets": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "size": 1429504,
        "download_count": 1,
        "browser_download_url": "https://dl.domain.tld/files/cdbc6e19-cd86-4ed6-8897-37ec5aaee578"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried to get the ID value like this:

```
$json_obj = json_decode($resp);
print $json_obj->assets[0]->id;
```

but I get no result whereas it should be 6. What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the outer part of the JSON is an array, as suggested by the opening `[`. So you need to first access the first (and only) element of it:

```
$json_obj[0]->assets[0]->id; //<-- note the first [0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct answer is

```
$json_obj = json_decode($resp);
print $json_obj[0]->assets[0]->id;
```

The json object will be converted to a php array, since you have an array with a object inside in your case it will be a multidimentional array with the objects inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try this its worked for me..

```
$json ='[
  {
    "assets": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "size": 1429504,
        "download_count": 1,
        "browser_download_url": "https://dl.domain.tld/files/cdbc6e19-cd86-4ed6-8897-37ec5aaee578"
      }
    ]
  }
]';



$json_obj = json_decode($json);

var_dump($json_obj[0]->assets[0]->id)
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

decode JSON to the array and fetch the id by proper array keys

```
$jToArray = json_decode($resp, TRUE);
echo $jToArray[0]['assets'][0]['id'];//You will get the correct id
```